# Primefaces p:messages dissappears after ajax call

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My problem is that `p:messages` error message flashes and then dissappears. I understand that my ajax on h:commandButton clears the form but I need to keep the message inside the form and I cannot get my method to run in other ways I.E. `p:commandButton` onclick.

My xhtml code snippet from card.xhtml template:

```
        <h:form id="cardForm">      
          <p:messages closable="true" id="msg">
            <p:autoUpdate disabled="true"/>
          </p:messages>
    
          <h:commandButton
            value="Add card to profile"
            actionListener="#{cust.addCardToProfile('cards.xhtml')}"
            rendered="#{not cart}">
            <p:ajax oncomplete="addCardToProfile();" update=":cardForm:msg"/>
           </h:commandButton>
        <h:form>
```

How to correctly run my "addCardToProfile();" -method and update messages so it stays on the screen.

Original xhtml:

```
    ...
  <p:remoteCommand name="addCard2OptionList"
   actionListener="#{saml2IdPLoginController.addCard2OptionList}"/>
    ...
      <p:outputPanel id="userCard">
          <ui:define name="content">
            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/card.xhtml"/>
          </ui:define>
      </p:outputPanel>
```

As suggested by @Melloware, It might have something to do with `RemoteCommand` component.

Comment: Tried with `p:messages redisplay="true" ...`?

Comment: `p:messages redisplay="true"` provides same outcome; Message flashes and dissappears.

Comment: Check your F12 network traffic you might have something showing the message and another AJAX call immediately clears the message because of `p:autoUpdate` I noticed `oncomplete="addCardToProfile();"` is Javascript so you have a RemoteCommand most likely making another AJAX call which wipes out the message?

Comment: @Melloware Checked the Javascript, it does not perform anything that should at least refresh or clear the form. Propably something to do with the `RemoteCommand`?
 Added original xhml to show how the code is structured.

Comment: Yep if you look your CommandButton is firing 1 AJAX request and updates MSGS with your message.   Then the RemoteCommand fires after that another AJAX request which then paints your Messages as EMPTY because you have a `p:autoUdpdate`. So on your RemoteCommand add `ignoreAutoUpdate="true"`

Comment: @Melloware unfortunately `ignoreAutoUpdate="true"` didn't solve the problem. It doesnt seem to change anything.

Comment: Hmm if you could put a small PrimeFaces Test reproducer for me I can debug the issue. See https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test